# How can i use OpenGL/Viewport render in rendered mode on cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, opengl

Whenever I do it on Eevee, it works. and I find it to be a great way to render faster, but whenever I do it on Cycles, I just get nothing besides a grey screen, Help? My render settings are on the default.

Example:

In Cycles:
[image]

In Eevee:
[image]

Comment: Please add details to your question. What scene did you create that you have a grey screen? Add screenshots of your lighting, materials and objects. What render settings did you use?

Comment: Yes, i added them now, and just to be clear to anyone else, this is not the F12 render, this is the OpenGL/Viewport render.